# Маршрутизация в ASP MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, view, controller, route

Есть контроллер, в котором определен метод GetAllPurchaseList, при переходе на него, система ищет представление с именем  GetAllPurchaseList.cshtml. Иметь представление с таким именем не очень удобно, можно ли указать методу контроллера, что нужно выбрать иное представление? Пробовал через Route, но почему то не получилось.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Controllers/HomeController

```
public ActionResult GetAllPurchaseList()
{
    return View("MyView", new MyModel());
}
```

Views/Home/MyView.cshtml

```
@model MyModel;
//html
```